# Copying/moving and renaming files from multiple subdirectories to parent directory

Tags: files, find, rename, cp

I have multiple directories, and each one of those directories contains an "example" directory which in turn contains images. What I want to do, is to add a textual suffix at the end of a filename (but which precedes the extension) to each file and then copy the contents of the directory into its respective parent directory.

Basically I want the files from /maindir/dir1/example/, /maindir/dir2/example etc. to be renamed and copied/moved to their respective parent directories, i.e. dir1 and dir2.  The contents of all "example" dirs are images with a .jpg extension.
I don't know if I am going about this the right way but I managed to figure out how to do the copying part by doing this:

```
find /path/to/folder/ -type d -name example  -execdir bash -c 'cp  "$1"/* .' cp {}   \;
```

which copies the content into the parent folder correctly, but I'm kinda stumped on how do I go about adding a suffix to the copied files while using find.

Comment: @Cbhihe I'm not sure I follow, basically I just want the files from /maindir/dir1/example/, /maindir/dir2/example etc. to be copied/moved to their respective parent directories, i.e. dir1 and dir2. Is that what you meant? The contents of all "example" dirs are images with the .jpg extensions. As long as the end result is the same using find is not required. As for collisions, the filenames are unique so that shouldn't be a problem, but I guess skipping already present files would be in order. the infix would be "-thumb" so image-thumb.jpg being the end result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use `find` and a `for` loop and for each `f`ile path use [parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal) to extract the extension (`t=${f##*.}`), the basename (`b=${f##*/}`) and the basename without extension (`${b%.*}`) so as to be able to create the destination name (`n=${b%.*}-thumb.${t}`):

```
find /path/to/folder/ -type d -name example  -execdir sh -c 'for f in "${1}"/*;
do t=${f##*.}; b=${f##*/}; n=${b%.*}-thumb.${t}; cp -- "$f" "$n"; done' cp {} \;
```

You can always insert an `echo` before `cp` to print what would be executed.

---

Another way with `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv
zmv -n '(**/)example/(*)(.*)' '${1}${2}-thumb${3}'
```

Replace the `-n` (dry-run) with `-C` to copy the files.

Comment: Yes, that did exactly what I wanted. Thank you.